# how to formulate elo table

Tags: algorithm, probability

I want to use the [elo table](http://www.ascotti.org/programming/chess/elo.htm). 
Is there a way to calculate the probability to win without hard coding the whole table.

from what I see, It's not a linear line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system

Look at that page for text "for the expected score of Player A is"

Ea = 1 / ((1 + 10^((RB - RA) / 400))

where Ea is the expected score for Player A

Comment: if `RB=1000` and `RA =1400` then then `Ea=-1/9` an the probability is negative

Comment: The formula Ea is the score that the chess player A is added or subtracted to his ELO points. You have to read the whole text of that page

Answer (score 0):

Calculation of the rating difference table as used by FIDE:

Let dp be the rating difference. Then expectation p equals (Excel):

```
=ROUND(ROUND(NORMDIST(dp * 7 / 2000;0;1;1);3);2)
```

There are two exception to this rule: `dp = 343` and `dp = 344`